# Are there CSS compilers which write the attributes for all browsers prefixes at compile?

Tags: css, sass, compilation

I'm using SCSS at the moment and that works wonderfully for giving me the ability to use variables and such, but it also gives me the ability to write functions which output the following if I gave it **-90**:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

I'm wondering if there are any staple engines that do this for all properties in CSS3, so you can simply write `transform: rotate(-90deg)` and at compile, it uses all the different properties that it can have, such as `webkit`, `moz`, `ms`, `o` and whatever other possibilities like `filter: progid:DXImag..blah..mage(rotation=3);` for IE also so it's all universal for browsers.

Comment: SCSS or LESS, you can use mixins to get what you want.

Comment: @Towkir thanks for your comment. I understand that I can use mixins (as stated in the post) but I was curious if there was an automatic system to do this all since it would boost written CSS to all browsers instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [AutoPrefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), which you can add to your build system and does exactly what you want. It can even add prefixes only for properties where it is still necessary based on [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com) data.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was after. Regards. :)